# Is it OK to use EVAL in this situation?

Tags: php

I'm coding a very simple template system for learning purposes only.

That said, I'm reading a TPL file that contains self-representations of IF and ELSE, sort of like "{if = $ a <10} case1 {else} case2 {/if}".

So, using regex, I go through the TPL file and reconstruct replacing the occurrences for conventional PHP code.

So,

```
{if = $ a <10} case1 {else} case2 {/if}
```

turns into

```
if ($ a <10) {echo "case1"; } else {echo "case2"; }
```

Ok.

But I have to run this as PHP code to get the result of this logic and then reassemble the template output.

And this is where my doubt comes in: I read that the **eval()** function should be avoided! And some people even say that if you need to use **eval()**, then it's because you programmed it wrong!

Is **eval()** the only way out of this case? Or are there other solutions that are more suitable for this applicability?

Comment: What happens when someone enters `{if = $ a <10 && shell_exec('rm -rf /*') } case1 {else} case2 {/if}` in your proposed templating engine?

Comment: I do not see any reason to use eval in your scenario. There is definitely a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Okay. I understand there is a security breach there! But given that the TPL file is created manually only by the project creator, how could the code be placed on the client side and run on the server side?

Comment: if its hardcoded, why not just use php?

Comment: Regardless of if you use eval or render the template to a PHP file and have the users request execute it, the security issues are still the same.  The big reason that eval and other functions that lead to dynamic code execution are considered bad practice is because the end user maybe able to inject code that will run on the server.  If you are controlling who is uploading the template and its not rendering based on user input, then I don't think it will be a big issue.  Its not the best practice, however, it beats writing your own domain specific language in PHP.

Comment: @MarceloBarganha If the templates are created manually by the project creator, why on earth wouldn't you just type `<?php echo $a < 10 ? 'case1' : 'case2'; ?>`?

Comment: @ceejayoz - I'm trying to separate code and views as much as possible. Also, I am dealing with a TPL file ...

Comment: @AlexBarker That's an awesome approach!

Comment: @MarceloBarganha Why not use one of the existing templating engines? Twig, Laravel's Blade, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz As I told, I'm coding a very simple template system for learning purposes only.

Comment: No: if it would be "very simple" you could choose approaches like `iflower = A B` and turn that into PHP code. But you want complexities like `if = anything`. Unmix that and you can easily evade `eval()` - just provide different IF-versions for all those you actually need.